# Need help optimizing an sql statement with several "field IN (subselect)" OR'd together

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Please advise how best to optimize this query.

```
select count(*)
from table1
where field1 in (select `text` from table2 where id=2)
   or field2 in (select `text` from table2 where id=2)
   or field3 in (select `text` from table2 where id=2);
```

My first thought was to select the result of the inner query into a comma separated value, then use the result in the csv in the IN clauses. But is there a way to do this entirely in SQL?

Comment: How badly is it performing? Can you quantify query times and row counts?

Comment: Not badly for now. But I envisage as table grows to million of rows, those multiple select statements might come to bite me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting to proper joins and inverting your table order so your `where id = 2` conditions can get some traction, and use `union` to split up the `OR` into separate queries that may allow indexes to be used:

```
select count(distinct id) from (
    select t.id
    from table2 t2
    join table1 t on t.field1 = t2.`text`
    where t2.id=2
    union
    select t.id
    from grouplists t2
    join table1 t on t.field2 = t2.`text`
    where t2.id=2
    union
    select t.id
    from grouplists t2
    join table1 t on t.field3 = t2.`text`
    where t2.id=2    
)
```

You'll often find that separate queries out-perform a single "or" based one, because each part of the "or" can then use its own (optimal) index.

Answer (score 1):

I like Bohemian's answer but I think this might work as an alternative also

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.id)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.text = table1.field1 
                AND table2.id=2
LEFT JOIN grouplists g1 ON g1.text = table1.field2 
                       AND g1.id=2
LEFT JOIN grouplists g2 ON g2.text = table1.field3 
                       AND g2.id=2
WHERE COALESCE(table2.id, g1.id, g2.id) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) "Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments", so it's removing the records that havent joined to anything in the other tabless